# What is the easiest way to getting distinct count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a distinct query as like below for three columns. My requirement is that I need a count of distinct of these three columns.

```
select distinct empid, empname, salary from employee
```

This is the following query used to getting the count of the table in normal case, but I needed that distinct count, how can I make a query ?

```
select count(empid) from employee
```

Comment: If `empid` is unique in the `employee` table then so is `empid, empname, salary`, or `empid + anything else`.  You're just going to get the same records and Count back.

Comment: It's a sample, My case the empid has some duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select count(*) from
(
    select distinct empid, empname, salary from employee
) x
```

Comment: This query looks good. Do you know any other alternative other than subquery ?

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to use a sub select just use group by

```
Select Count(*) FROM employee GROUP BY empid, empname, salary
```